# How to detach all processes from terminal and still get stdout in Docker?

Tags: linux, unix, docker, nohup

So it's easy to detach applications if you're calling them directly using something like

```
myapplication &
```

But what if I want to call `myapplication` which then forks off 100 `mychildapplication` processes? Well, apparently the same command still works. I can run it, exit the terminal, and see that the child processes are still there.

It gets complicated when I introduce a Docker container.

If I were to run `docker exec -it --user myuser mycontainer sh -c 'source ~/.bashrc; cd mydir; ./myapplication myarg'` in a Docker container, the child processes get killed right away. I can hack it by appending a sleep 10000000 but of course then my terminal will hang indefinitely.

I can also use `nohup`, but then I don't get the stdout. `disown` does not work because it's not running in the background.

My workaround right now is using jpetazzo:nsenter, but I don't want to type my password when I run the command.

*Note: the reason I have all this sudo stuff is because exec doesn't source bashrc. I can hack it by manually sourcing bashrc and it would work. It doesn't really impact what I'm trying to do.*

**TLDR**: I want `myapplication` to print to my terminal, finish executing, and have the child processes stick around after I exit, all in a Docker container. The only way this can happen is if somehow I can "nohup" *all* processes associated with my terminal.

Comment: have you tried  `-d, --detach`? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

Comment: detached does the same except it puts it in the background like ctrl-z. Still gets killed.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand why you'd like to do that. Can't you run `./myapplication myarg` as the `ENTRYPOINT` in Dockerfile?

Comment: @bferreira the container has interdependent binaries I'd like to run. Binaries also take various args and need the environment to be set correctly, sourcing bashrc.

Comment: I've created a script with an inifite loop and by running `docker exec -it -d --user myuser mycontainer sh -c 'source ~/.bashrc; cd mydir; ./myapp.sh'` the process is not killed. When I entered the container `docker exec -it --user myuser mycontainer bash` giving a `ps` it shows my process is still running `myuser+   124  0.0  0.0  11636  1376 ?        S+   16:39   0:00 /bin/bash ./myapp.sh`. Perhaps the problem is related with `./myapplication` content!?

Comment: You misunderstood the question. Myapp.sh doesn't have the loop, it forks child processes that have the infinite loop. These child processes get killed when docker exec returns when myapp.sh returns.